# Do I have any performance gain using the BufferedReader in this case?

Tags: java

I want to send a CSV file encoded in base64 from Client to Server, in order to parse it and use the data.
I want to get the InputStream directly from the Request object and pipe it to the reader used by the CSV parser.

- Is there any performance or memory gain using this method?
- Can the following code achieve this ?  I feel like there's something missing while decoding the content.
- Is BufferedReader really needed in this example ?

  ```
  /* Suppose I get a Base64 encoded CSV file from the client */
  String csvContent = "Column 1;Column 2;Column 3\r\nValue 1;Value 2;Value 3\r\n";
  ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.encodeBase64(csvContent.getBytes()));

  /* retrieving the content UPDATED */
  Base64InputStream b64InputStream = new Base64InputStream(inputStream, false);

  /* Parsing the CSV content */
  Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(b64InputStream));

  CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, FORMAT_EXCEL_FR);           

  /* printing results */
  csvParser.forEach(record -> printRecord(record));
  ```

**Update**
I replaced the `byte[]` array with a `Base64InputStream` from `org.apache.commons.codec`

Comment: profile it and see

Comment: @Michael while I agree that >80% of performance questions can be answered with "profile it". This is an exception. - It would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not. A `BufferedReader` ... uses a buffer. It is commonly used when your data is not in java memory yet. ( e.g. socket communication, reading data from a file , ... )

In your case, you are wrapping a `byte[]`, which means that the data is already in memory. So there is no point in adding a buffer.

The javadoc describes a `BufferedReader` as follows:

> Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.

Now, let's say for example you want to read the content of a file, and want to check something byte-per-byte. So you do a lot of `byte b = in.read();` calls. In that case, a buffered reader will actually fetch those bytes in chunks internally.

**So, basically, whenever it is more efficient to fetch data in chunks, use a `BufferedReader`.**

## Update

In response to your update. No, also in this case it's not necessary to add a `BufferedReader`. As Holger pointed out:

> It's likely that the CSVParser does that already (i.e. buffering).

I checked the source code of the `CSVParser`, and look what's in the constructor.

```
public CSVParser(final Reader reader, final CSVFormat format, final long characterOffset, final long recordNumber)
        throws IOException {
    ...
    this.lexer = new Lexer(format, new ExtendedBufferedReader(reader));
    ...
}
```

It wraps some kind of buffered reader by default. So, there's no need to add one yourself.

Comment: Regarding the conclusion in the last sentence, it should be noted that “whenever it is more efficient to fetch data in chunks”, it’s worth doing exactly that, i.e use the `read` methods which accepts an array to fill, with an appropriately sized array. It’s likely that the `CSVParser` of the example does that already, if its author(s) did it well. So then, a `BufferedReader` still is unnecessary. And well, `InputStreamReader` needs to use a charset decoder internally, which also works on chunks of data (aka buffers), so there’s already a buffering going on at this place too.

Comment: I updated the code can you please have look and tell if it is safer now

Comment: @Holger, good point, indeed, if there already is some kind of buffering, then there is no need to add a 2nd level of buffering.